# How to call AWS S3 image URL from android(Client) when the authentication with S3 is from server-side(php+ aws sdk php v3)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-image, aws-php-sdk

I have android as front-end, (php,mysql) as back-end and AWS as the infrastructure host. I am developing APIs using laravel to be consumed by the android app but having problem figuring out how to display images hosted on S3 in android.
I am able to fetch (private)resource URL from S3 using the AWS PHP SDK's *getObjectURL* method but I can't pass the URL alone as an image src in Android as the URL does not contain credentials and authentication is only happening from server side.
Should I first download images from S3 to my server, cache it and serve to Android or is there a way I can have android directly access the images from the URL i.e. can i append credentials with URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access images from s3 bucket using Andriod SDK 
see this : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

Comment: Yeah, but my business logic is held in server-side APIs, do you suggest I maintain S3 logic in Android ?

Comment: I sujject you to maintain only for render images from s3 using your business logic references in the BeanClass.If you can access key for brows files from s3 it will be the best solution for you!